# How to send data from AWS Lambda with VPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, vpn, aws-nat-gateway

I have an AWS lambda function that sends data to server outside of AWS.

The server will start to work with VPN, so I need to define a VPN client in my AWS account.

Is it possible to make my AWS Lambda to work with VPN?

If not, what is the best and easiest option (e.g. set an EC2 with VPn to forward normal traffic to VPN traffic, define nat instance with VPN, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

Lambda can access the resources in your private vpc and you can create a VPN between your vpc and on-premise server.

**Configuring lambda on your vpc:-**

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-access-resources-in-a-vpc-from-your-lambda-functions/

**VPC VPN Configuration:**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_VPN.html

Hope this should be helpful